# Is it possible to programmatically force a screen update in Excel from VSTO using C#?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2016

Is it possible to force a screen update in Excel 2016 from VSTO using the methods of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace?

If I use the following code to set column widths, the result is "snaking" columns or columns of differing width.

```
  activeWorksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 50;

  for (int formatCol = 2; formatCol <= 15; formatCol++)
        activeWorksheet.Columns[formatCol].ColumnWidth = 25;
```

The image below shows the results of setting the column width:
[image]

The column headers on row 8 do not reflect the column widths set in code.

If the code to set column width is commented out, the worksheet looks like this:
[image]

Calls to `AutoFit()` produce similar results.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by screen update?

Comment: and whats happening to require this?

Comment: By screen update - I mean something similar to a paint or update.  It appears that the worksheet does not properly show the effects of updating column widths.

Comment: Did you try to encapsulate your code by ``XlApp.ScreenUpdating`` ?

Comment: No, can I do that in VSTO and C#?

Comment: I added the following line to the top of my method:  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
Is there a way to invalidate the current worksheet and force an update?